# People from my country in a word

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

I want to write a sentence something like this - >

I like to meet **people of my native origin(country, city, town and so on)**.

How can i write the things that are in bold in one word - >

I like to meet ____

Comment: You might consider "landsmen."

Comment: @deadrat Doesn't get the desired effect.

Comment: A landsman is someone you have a connection to because he or she comes from the same place as you and has the same background that you do.  What "effect" are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What is the word in your mother tongue? Which dictionaries have you looked up the translation in? What did they say? Why do their translations not work for you? Please specify. We cannot be playing a game of "perfectly valid word — not the desired effect — perfectly valid word — not the desired effect". Clearly state right from the start what the desired effect is and which words you've considered and rejected. Thank you.

Comment: I've never heard of landsman as "countryman", only ever as the opposite to "seaman" (i.e. as a synonym of "landlubber").

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Compatriot**:

> a fellow citizen or national of a country.
>   "Stich defeated his compatriot Boris Becker in the quarter-finals"
>   synonyms: fellow countryman, fellow countrywoman, countryman, countrywoman, fellow citizen, fellow national

I disagree with "countryman" as a synonym: it's in a famous speech in Shakespeare's *Julius Caesar* ("Friends, Romans, Countrymen, lend me your ears...") but it's archaic IMO.

Compatriot sounds archaic to me too, but less so.

I suggest a "fellow *something*". Or specify which place you're talking about (e.g. "Canadians", "Ontarians", "people from Ottawa").

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps the word you require is *[compatriot](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/compatriot)*:-

> 1. A person from one's own country. [American Heritage Dictionary via the Free Dictionary]